# Why is MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS ignored?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using mysqli to connect my php code to mysql, and I am using the MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS option to ensure that my UPDATE statements will return non-zero even if they try to update a record with the same values that it already holds.

```
$mysqli->real_connect(
            $this->DB_HOST,
            $this->DB_USERNAME,
            $this->DB_PASSWORD,
            $this->DB_DATABASE,
            3306,
            null,
            MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS
    );
```

I have one box where it works: php53, mysql 5.1.54-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
I now installed a new box where it doesn't work: php 53, mysql 5.1.44 - Source distribution

in the first box, the statement's 'affected_rows' is 1. On the second box it's 0.

software info for the non-working box:

```
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

phpinfo for the non working box (I hope this is enough detail):
    mysql

```
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.1.44
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.1.44
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.1.44
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
```

php info for the working box:

```
mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.1.54
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   no value
MYSQL_SOCKET    /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   no value
MYSQL_LIBS  no value

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock    /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  zend    zend
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.1.54
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.1.54
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock    /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user zend    zend
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off
```

any ideas why? I'm banging my head here... it's unlikely that a minor build number diff between the two mysqls is the cause of this...

Comment: Here's a page with docs for the flag: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php  Note: sometimes a build from source can have unusual or different options than mainline build.

Comment: Did you see anything in the phpinfo about the driver being used, or if `mysqlnd` is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

when using a php with mysqlnd enabled instead of the mysql native client, it works well. But I was unable to rebuild PHP for numerous reasons. I ended up installing a new PHP via macports (port install php53 php53-mysql) to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS
```

try using integer

```
2
```

Like this:

```
$mysqli->real_connect(
        $this->DB_HOST,
        $this->DB_USERNAME,
        $this->DB_PASSWORD,
        $this->DB_DATABASE,
        3306,
        null,
        2
);
```

It solved issue for me....